# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between the phrase "who knows" and "who is to know"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Is there any difference in meaning and usage between the phrase *who knows* and *who is to know*? For example:

> Maybe in ten years people will settle on Mars. **Who knows**?
>
> Maybe in ten years people will settle on Mars. **Who is to know**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example uses the phrase **Who knows?** correctly. It's a rhetorical question -another way of saying that nobody knows whether people will settle on Mars in ten years.

Your second example is not idiomatic in this context. **Who is to know** is a way of asking rhetorically **who will find out**. It suggests that nobody will discover who is responsible if some undesirable or unlawful act is carried out.

> Let us take the money from the purse; who is to know?
>   Cash the lottery ticket we found; who is to know?
>   Nobody will see if you slip the book into your pocket; who is to know?

https://forum.english.best/t/who-is-to-know/56049